SwiftUI NavigationLink goes back immediately on first activation after app launch
I am experiencing an issue with programmatic navigation in my SwiftUI app. I use a NavigationLink with an isActive binding to navigate to a specific view (EditUser). The first time I toggle the binding (navigateToEditUser) after the app launches, the navigation occurs but immediately goes back. On subsequent activations, it works as expected. This issue repeats every time I restart the app.
Here is the relevant code snippet:
NavigationLink(
    destination: EditarUsuario(),
    isActive: $navigateToEditUser
) {
    EmptyView()
}

The binding (navigateToEditUser) is toggled from within a .sheet like this:
.onNavigateToEditUserData: {
    navigateToEditUser = true
}

I have tried:

Delaying the toggle with DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter.
Adding explicit state resets (onDisappear and onAppear).
Wrapping the NavigationLink with a custom binding to stabilize state changes.

None of these solutions have resolved the problem. I suspect it might be related to how SwiftUI re-renders the view hierarchy or handles NavigationLink's isActive state during initialization.
What could be causing this behaviour, and how can I ensure consistent navigation without the first activation issue?
Providing more details about full navigation flow:
struct compactNavigation: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var state: AppState

    var handler: Binding<String?> { Binding(
        get: { state.selectedTab },
        set: {
            let tab = state.selectedTab
            if $0 == tab {
                state.resetTab.toggle()
                print("Reset tab")
            } else {
                Tutorial.shared.stop()
            }
            state.selectedTab = $0
        }
    )}

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: handler) {
            NavigationView {
                Settings()
            }
            .tabItem { Label("settings", systemImage: "gearshape.fill") }
            .tag(Settings.tag)
        }
    }

}


struct Settings: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("account")) {
                NavigationLink(destination:
                    PlanView()
                ) {
                    Text("plan")
                        .font(.headline)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct PlanView: View {

    @State var showFilterEditor = false
    @State var navigateToEditUser = false

    var body : some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: EditarUsuario(),
                    isActive: $navigateToEditUser
                ) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                // Rest of the view content...
            }
        }
        .toolbar(content: {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                Button(action: {
                    showFilterEditor.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Label(title: { Text("filter") },
                          icon: { Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3") })
                })
            }
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showFilterEditor, content: {
            NutritionalPlanParameterEditor(
                onNavigateToEditUserData: {
                    navigateToEditUser = true
                }
            )
        })
    }
}


You should ensure that the navigation is correctly following the value of navigateToEditUser. Note, that this value isn't an event, it's a state. If you figure out it's correct, and I suspect it is, then there's code which changes the value of navigateToEditUser, which you haven't shown. You might add a custom binding to be able to set a breakpoint in the setter, so that you can easily see where its change  is coming from. Also, consider to upgrade to the new form. The current form is deprecated (see docs).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

The Navigation link you are using has been deprecated for years

Thanks for pointing it out. The app currently support iOS 15 and new NavigationStack was introduced at iOS 16. For now, iOS 15 will remain with this bug and I will go for NavigationStack for newer iOS versions. Thank you very much!

@IñigoBereciartua, please share minimal reproducible code

@Immanuel have added more code to reproduce full navigation flow of the app to that point

@IñigoBereciartua I tried with your code, but could not reproduce the issue, https://gist.github.com/immanaro2497/fdac35460509dae0d624980507d293db

I have NavigationView for NavigationStack (at compactNavigation.swift) as mentioned at previous comments and the error has been fixed. I have reached an agreement with UX team so that people will need to update to iOS 16 to prevent this from happening... :). Thanks for your responses!

Combine NavigationLink with onAppear
If you must use NavigationLink and a binding, reset the binding value in onAppear of the destination view:
NavigationLink(
    destination: EditarUsuario().onAppear {
        navigateToEditUser = false
    },
    isActive: $navigateToEditUser
) {
    EmptyView()
}

This ensures the navigation state (navigateToEditUser) resets correctly once the destination view appears.

It still has the same behaviour
